# Using depth texture for depth testing

Tags: opengl, shaders

I was wondering if it is possible to render my scene onto a depth texture then using that texture for depth testing in another pass. I have an idea to that in shaders, but is that possible hardware-side?

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this would be to use an FBO (Frame Buffer Object) and multiple depth buffers and/or depth textures. A basic use case is shown [on the Wiki at OpenGL.org](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples#Quick_example.2C_render_to_texture_.282D.29.2C_mipmaps.2C_depth_stencil).

---

Another possible method, maybe applicable to old or very low end hardware could be copying the depth buffer, which you can find an example of [using PBOs (Pixel Buffer Objects) here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html).